# RF connector/ interconnect for Gate signals

Tags: rf, connector, interconnect, bnc

I need connector as shown in pictures. I spent good couple of hours trying to find them on Farnell but the lingo for such connectors is little difficult for me. I read a lot too but couldn't find those. Can anyone tell me what to search for?[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your typical female coax connections (possibly F connections?)

Comment: Is it a typical one, esp with the small gold plated one attached to the BNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BNC Female (Jack) to SMB Female (Jack)

A labeled example is at: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rosenberger/59K151-K00L5/1868-1416-ND/7927117

Answer (score 2):

Thats an adaptor, the silver end is a BNC female, not too sure what the gold end is, some measurements would help.

Maybe a SMB or such (But there are a plethora of similar microwave connectors, so you really need to measure the damn thing).